# Why does not std::priority_queue constructor work?

Tags: c++, priority-queue

Why is it that when I call the same constructor, it works in one case, but not in the other?

```
std::vector<ulli> v(n);
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    inf >> v[i];
}
std::priority_queue<ulli> q1(std::greater<ulli>(), v);  //  fails
std::priority_queue<ulli> q2(std::less<ulli>(), v);  //  works
```

Comment: Please share class `ulli`.

Comment: Also copy-paste your error message.

Comment: @Sergey It seems the operator > is not defined for the class ulli.

Comment: Assuming ulli is a typedef of `unsigned long long int`, the problem isn't actually missing `operator >` but [some sort of CTAD failure](https://godbolt.org/z/E4cq7xTdP)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the default template parameter, the `Compare` of `std::priority_queue<ulli>` is of type `std::less`, and in your first example, you use `std::greater` to initialize `std::less`, which is not correct.

With help of CTAD, just

```
std::priority_queue q1(std::greater<ulli>(), v);
```

Comment: I would hope that class template argument deduction would be able to figure out that the comparator is `std::greater<ulli>`, just like in the second case it's able to figure out that the container is `std::vector<ulli, std::allocator<ulli>>`. (EDIT: Oh, is the issue that including `std::priority_queue<ulli>` immediately instantiates the entire class with default arguments, which worked fine for the `std::less` / `std::vector` case? Fascinating.)

Comment: "*just like in the second case it's able to figure out that the container i*" No,  the actual type of `std::priority_queue<ulli>` is `std::priority_queue<ulli, std::vector<ulli>, std::less<ulli>>`.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from this  page on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue), `std::priority_queue<T>` has two defaulted template parameters:

- one being its container type (`Container = std::vector<T>`);
- and the other being its comparator type (`Compare = std::less<T>`).

So,

```
std::priority_queue<ulli>
```

indeed means

```
std::priority_queue<ulli, std::vector<ulli>, std::less<ulli>>
```

and provides no constructor that takes a `std::greater<ulli>` as comparator.

You should declare `q1` as

```
std::priority_queue<ulli, std::vector<ulli>, std::greater<ulli>> q1(std::greater<ulli>(), v);
```

Or, if you're in C++17 (or newer), just:

```
std::priority_queue q1(std::greater<ulli>(), v);
```